# Is labevents table having lab values for tests before and after ICU admission?

Tags: mimic-iii

I am noticing, that labevents table has labs values, from before and after critical care units admissions - icu stays, correct me please if I am wrong ?

So lets say there is patient X coming into ICU for 4 days, then staying in the wards (usual floor, not ICU) within the hospital and obtains more bloodwork, i understand, there is a high change of these results of bloodwork, also goes into labevents table ?

Always sometimes ?

Comment: What about MIMIC III waveforms- is there any news soon for release?

Answer (score 2):

The [MIMIC documentation](https://mimic.physionet.org/mimictables/labevents/) notes that:

> - The labevents table contains both in-hospital laboratory measurements and out of hospital laboratory measurements from clinics which the patient has visited. Laboratory measurements for outpatients do not have a HADM_ID.
> - ...there is a subset of patients for which the outpatient lab data is not available. They can be identified by checking for patients whose data always has an HADM_ID.